# Dividing a whole into 2 with a dynamic ratio

Tags: functions, approximation, ratio

Hi I did my best in the title but I have a question which it feels like people have surely come across before and has a known or standard way of doing it.

Basically I have a whole(a number) which I want to divide into 2 parts. Let's call these $x$ and $y$. The value of $y$ depend on $x$. In other words the bigger the $x$ is, bigger the $y$ gets. So the ratio between $x$ and $y$ is depend on how big the $x$ is.

Example: Let's call our whole $N$. So $N = x + y$ and lets say if $x < 10$ , then $x = y$
if $ 10 <= x < 20$ then $y = 2x$ and if $x >= 20$ then $y = 3x$ and so on. That is just an example and actual function between $x$ and $y$ is different and continuous. Not discrete.

So the question is, given a $N_{max}$ how can I calculate the $x_{max}$? Obviously you can do it iteratively by try and guess what the max x can be but I thought there should be a function or a  known way of doing this. Also ratio doesn't have to exactly be sum up to $N_{max}$, it can be an approximation as well. So I am guessing an approximation function might also work.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. I get that you want the ratio of $x$ and $y$ to get larger with the value of $x$, but do you know what the ratio has to be? In other words, you have
$$
N = x+y
$$
and
$$
y = f(x) \cdot x
 $$
where $f(x)$ is an increasing function. Now
$$
N = x + f(x) \cdot x = (1+f(x))\cdot x
$$
Do you know anything about this function $f(x)$ ?

Comment: @MattiP. So `N` is fixed but you want to find x value that satisfies(at least approximately) `N = x+y` where y is also a function of `x` like `y = x^2`.

Comment: If I don't know what the ratio function is, it's difficult to solve any equations or maximum values ...

Comment: @MattiP we can assume that y = x^2 . Then there should be a way approximation for the biggest x we can have.

Comment: Assuming $y=x^2 $, we have the problem of finding the largest (integer?) value of $x$ so that
$$
x + x^2 \leq N
$$
or
$$
x^2 +x - N \leq 0
$$
Solving for the **equation** part ($x^2 + x - N = 0$), we get
$$\tag{1}
x = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4N}}{2}
$$
You want to take the plus-signed value of that. Most likely this returns a real number, so if you want the integer part of that, you can take the floor function of that. Satisfied? For example with $N=100$, you get $x\approx 9.512$, the integer part of which is $9$. Note that Equation 1 only applies with the assumed $y=x^2$.

Comment: More generally, if you have $y=g(x)$ then you want to solve
$$
x+ g(x) \approx N
$$
If $g$ is some nastier function, you can indeed use iteration to solve the equation. Newton's method could work pretty well here, if you can differentiate $g$.

Comment: @MattiP thanks for the info. The function g(x)  indeed turned out to be  way more nastier than x^2. I think iteration method is the best. Thanks!.